# Combine files in multiple folders into one folder on Mac or read multiple files in different folders simultaneously in R

Tags: r, macos, read-data

Is there a quick way on Mac to put thousands of files from different folders into one folder or is there a way for R to read thousands of files in different working directories simultaneously?

Comment: What do you mean by different directories? Are these directories sub directory of one parent directory? Else what's the criteria to identify these directories?

Comment: for example, I have a folder A, which includes 3 subfolders b1, b2, b3, and each of the subfolders contains .rds files I need to read into R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some relevant details are missing from your question (e.g. file format, whether all the subfolders are in the same main folder). However, you may wanna look over two functions:

```
list.files()
```

combined to

```
lapply()
```

When reading the files are a good place to start. Please provide more details so we can help you in a better way.

Comment: sorry about the incomplete information, for example, I have a folder A, which includes 3 subfolders b1, b2, b3, and each of the subfolders contains .rds files I need to read into R.

Comment: Oh thanks for clarifying. If your workspace is set to A, you could try the following:

files<-list.files(path = '.',pattern='rds', recursive = T, full.names = T)
rds_files <- lapply(files, readRDS)

You can also do purr :)
       
library(purrr)
rds_files<-purrr::map_df(files, readRDS)

Comment: Thanks! Another question, what is the order of the elements in the rds_files, there are no names for each element in it, so it is hard to know which element is which file in the original folders

Comment: Here's some additional information: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/list.files. You can also do ?list.files in R to retrieve the same information. Note that the full.names = T argument should give you the full name for each of the files